# Cast map value on TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm very confused about how Map entries are managed on TypeScript

Consider the following code:

```
const foo = new Map();
foo.set(1, "1");
console.log('foo=', foo);
const myValue = foo.get(1) as number;
console.log('foo as number %i ', myValue );
console.log('foo as string %s ', myValue );
```

Gives me NaN with %i and works fine with %s

Change the code to

```
const myValue = +foo.get(1);
```

Works for me but looks like a ugly workaround.

What is the correct way to parse a get() on a Map object?

Comment: The map does not change the types of the values it contains. You put a string at key `1`, you get a string back. The type assertion (`as number`) does not change the type of the value stored in `myValue`. It is just a hint for the TypeScript compiler but it does not have any effect in the generated JavaScript code. All in all, the first 4 lines of code have the same effect as `const myValue = "1";`.

Comment: The posted code works as expected and [prints `1` in both cases](https://tio.run/##bY3BCsIwEETvfsVSKE2hLfTiRXr02JPgPYZtCKRJyG6R/rwxAUVEr/PmzfAekFQ0gVNS3hHD4j1M4PAOswyiPR1yMBCyGDuoxioHpectDtZr0WQ6NV2xXoRh3a/SbphXiqqL2oIkcNt6w/jrfxjUBvLYe6D93yWOxmmo6bub0kMtVmpKfc8y5t90vhyf).

Comment: Interesting, I can't reproduce the same error on https://tio.run/
Probably is a compiler option. But the comments and the answer are good enough to solve my questions for now, thanks.

Comment: It produces the same results on my local Node 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use generics and parseInt:

```js
type StirngNumber<T extends number>=`${T}`
const foo = new Map<number, StirngNumber<number>>();
foo.set(1, "1");
const val = foo.get(1)
const myValue = val ? parseInt(val, 10) : 'can find a value' // string | undefined
console.log(myValue);
```

Comment: The generics are just hints for the TypeScript compiler. They do not change the generated JavaScript code and they do not change the types of the values.

Comment: I know, also I provided `StringNumber` type for type safety.
I'm asking, whats wrong with my answer that you downvoted it?